# IE8/IE7/IE6 seem to treat anchor tag inserted via JQuery as a block level element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using CSS to absolutely position `small` elements from within paragraphs off to the side of said paragraphs. No issues there.

I'm then looking to use javascript to, among other things, insert a linked superscript digit before the `small` element.

Basically, changing this:

```
<p>
    <small> ... </small>
</p>
```

to this:

```
<p>
    <sup>
        <a href="#article1_note1">1</a>
    </sup>
    <small class="note" id="article1_note1"> ... </small>
</p>
```

This is where the layout breaks in IE8 or earlier. (It may, for all I know, break in IE9 as well, but I only have XP boxes available for testing.)

Process of elimination suggests that the `a` tag is the ultimate culprit. These browsers seem like they're treating it as a block level element. Adding a `display: inline` to the style rules didn't seem to fix this.

The odd thing is that, if I take the generated source and save it as a static HTML document, it displays just fine in those same browsers.

As far as I can tell, then, the issue is caused by the anchor tag's dynamic insertion via JS/JQuery.

Here's a jsFiddle test page I've created:

http://jsfiddle.net/D6SMH/show/

Here's a version with the script removed and the HTML replaced by the generated HTML of the latter:

http://jsfiddle.net/VJT2N/show/

Both display identically in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Only the latter, hard-coded version displays properly in the IE offenders.

Comment: after inspecting the html, it looks like your sup tags are becoming div tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly close your html tags in jQuery.

```
notes.eq(j).before('<sup><a href="#' + noteid + '">' + (j+1) + '</a></sup>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D6SMH/2/

Comment: @mkoryak IE does not handle it correctly, the other browsers do.

Comment: @mkoryak See the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 the snippet passed in must be well-formed or the results may vary from browser to browser.

Comment: Ah... So just the result of poor form on my part. Same as it ever was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because your CSS declaration to vertical-align: super; To handle this request it may be transforming your  tags into a block element. You may want look at another workaround (negative margin-top, etc) in a conditional stylesheet.

Comment: Simply closing the `sup` and `a` tags in the script (per Kevin B) seems to have done the trick. But thanks.